# Can someone recommend a Compact Flash card to be used as a boot disk/fixed disk

Tags: ssd, acer-aspire-one, compact-flash

I have an early Acer Aspire One netbook, and the flash drive is really slow at writing. I've taken it apart to add more RAM, but I've pretty much stopped using it. I've read about people [replacing the SSD with a Compact Flash card and a CF to ZIF adapter](http://www.liliputing.com/2008/07/how-to-replace-the-ssd-in-the-acer-aspire-one.html) but I've also read about some Compact Flash cards where the manufacturer has permanently disabled the boot flag to stop people doing this kind of mod. (Can't find the link any more though). (Although I have just found [some info about CF cards](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Compact_Flash_boot_drive) that says "Most CompactFlash cards by default identify themselves as removable media instead of fixed disk" and that this is an issue for Windows.

So my most specific question is: can someone recommend a compact flash card that does allow the boot flag to be set and to be set as Fixed Disk? Please say whether you've done it yourself, or just heard about it from someone else.

Beyond that, is this generally a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These work fine as a fixed disk for this purpose, they are set to "fixed disk" immediately without having to set it:

- Transcend 133X/266X/300X

These should work too, but I'm not sure:

- Photofast 533X

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be a sdram slot why cant you use a usb slot?

Yes at least 30 to 40 percent will be able to boot, remember you must direct the bios to it it will not simply pick it at randome/ I

Ive done it with some cheapos Patriot 2g and 4 g Transend 8g, Lexar not to mention you can go to places like snapfiles.com and download freeware that will fix that issue, recover damaged data, undelete and make them react just like a hard drive.

Make sure you dont have a virus thats not being picked up. I had a malware virus I got from playing a snoop dog x video and it started out telling me I needed some #w player and it was free and I must go to xyz.com to download it (Just search for the 3w video virus and you will get a lot of info. Anyway not only is the file itself packed with a bunch of nightmarish spyware and malware but ut will go through each good video you have (It did this on a Western Digital Studio Live that I recently bought and infected every file on an external drive that I had hooked to it with about 20 nice videos onit. I am not into rap so I never opened the snoop dog video up.  I enjoyed watching the other videos at least 3 to 5 times each.

One night I was bored and launched that snop file What a nightmare. Stupid me I figure I might as well download the player Someone went through 700 megs download its the least I can do who knows it might be a good video. OH NO that sucker had more undetectable viruses and malware and other wares I almost went nuts tryng to figure it out.

It sounded a lot like what your describing.

Somehow you can check your up and download dsl speeds and your result will be great, truly great. BUT somehow the virus or malare makes the video board slow down and create a bottleneck. It took me forever to figure out the problem as a matter a fact it why I tunred to linux YLMF was I couldnt stand the slow speeds. Crazy download at 500k yet it would take forever for a web page to load. Drove me crazy.

Keep your eyes open for the same nightmware.

Coley